# How can i get ALL File Extentions in C#?

Tags: c#, directory

```
string path = "C:\\BSD";
string extension = Console.ReadLine();
List<string> allExstensions = getAllExtention(); // Is there a method where I get all File Extensions : *.png, *.txt,.......
if (!allExstensions.Contains(extension))
    throw new Exception("The Extension you wrote does not exist!!");

foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directory,extension))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
```

Is there a method to check if the enterf exstention exsits?

Comment: No, a file can have any arbitrary extension or none at all. There is a concept of "registered" extensions, but you don't need to register a file extension to use it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What extensions do you consider valid? Your question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 3):

A file can have whatever extension it wants.  It can be any sequence of characters of any length.  Since that sequence is infinite, there is no way to put them all in a list.

If you want to know if the directory you're interested in has any files with a given extension, you can enumerate all of the files in the directory and put all of their extensions into a set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using Linq:

```
    string path = "C:\\BSD";
    string extension = Console.ReadLine();
    int count = 0;

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => x.EndsWith(extension)))
    {
       Console.WriteLine(file);
       count++;
    }

    if (count == 0)
      throw new Exception("The Extension you wrote does not exist!!");
```